# Elasticsearch rollover to a new index every day + merge of the previous day

Tags: elasticsearch

I have elasticsearch with an index running. This index called `store`. This index contains millions of items.

I'm trying to create a secondary index that will collect all the new items to be inserted to the `store` index. This new index will be roll over to a new index every day. For example:

- `store_01_01_2001`
- `store_02_01_2001`
- `store_03_01_2001`
- ...

Up to this point, this is a simple rollup index that create a new index every N days.

Next thing that I want to achieve is that the day I will copy the previously created index back to `store` and remove the index from the cluster. For example: when creating the index `store_02_01_2001`, the index `store_01_01_2001` will be copied into the `store` index and than be deleted.

I know that I can do this automation with an additional programing language. But, is this possible to do it with ES alone?

Comment: I have a couple of questions. I see that you don't want to add records directly to `store`. Why? What problem are you trying to solve? Once you add the content of today's index to the `store`, do you plan to keep all records in the store forever?

Comment: @imotov I want to keep the `store` index as untouched as possible since I want to make more queries against it. The docs are remain in `store` forever.

Comment: I don't quite follow your logic though. What do you think is going to happen when "the index store_01_01_2001 will be copied into the store index"? You are basically indexing all records into the store index. Overall, you are doubling the load on your cluster by indexing each record twice - once in store_today and another time by indexing it into the store.

Comment: @imotov the logic is that it better to index 1M document in one time, instead of index it all over the day. The smaller index will be faster to ingest the data. The bigger one will ingest the smaller index once a day. It will improve the search performances overall.

Comment: Well, if you tested it and your tests showed that it is better, it is probably better. I would expect that you can achieve similar or better performance by setting long enough `refresh_interval` and using a single index. But perhaps with very uneven traffic during the day, your approach might produce better results.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, ILM wasn't designed to support this scenario. In order to do something like this you would need to reindex all records from the today's index into the common index, and reindex is not one of the [ILM action](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/ilm-actions.html) at the moment. There is an [open issue with a request for such feature](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/42784). But it didn't have any activity since July 2019, so I wouldn't expect it to be implemented any time soon.